# curl_easy_getinfo does not return correct size after upload

Tags: c++, curl

I have this code as below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

size_t read_file_data(char* buffer, size_t size,
                      size_t nitems, void* instream) {
    printf("\nUpload file binary data");
    cout << "Read" << nitems << " items by " << size << " bytes" << endl;

    size_t retcode = fread(buffer, size, nitems,
                           static_cast<FILE*>(instream));
    size_t retsize = size * retcode;
    cout << "Read " << retsize << "bytes from file\n";
    return retsize;
}

int main(void)
{
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (!curl) {
      return 1;
    }
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://172.30.191.145:3000/upload");

    struct curl_slist* chunk = NULL;
    chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Transfer-Encoding: chunked");
    chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk,
                              "Content-type:application/octet-stream");
    chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Session: test");
    CURLcode result = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, chunk);
    FILE* fp = 
        fopen("/home/thinh/Documents/SDL/curlupload/testfile.txt","rb");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION,
                     &read_file_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, fp);

    result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    cout << "curl result " << result << endl;

    CURLcode get_info_result;
    double val = 0;
    get_info_result = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_SIZE_UPLOAD, &val);
    if (CURLE_OK == get_info_result) {
      printf("Size of uploaded data:  %0.0f bytes.\n", val);
    } else {
      printf("ERROR");
    }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_slist_free_all(chunk);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

After execute, the Size of uploaded data always larger than actual file size.
But the file after uploaded in server is correct(same with local file)
I use `ll command` to check file size

problem in this line

```
get_info_result = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_SIZE_UPLOAD, &val);
```

For example: I upload local file text.txt 1022 bytes, but in log: "Size of uploaded data: 1034 bytes.", in server it is 1022 bytes.
text.txt content:

> abcd123
>   abcd123
>   abcd123

I couldn't find any document talk detail about upload file size.

Comment: What is the data that you upload? Does it contain newlines that are translated to `\r\n` sequences?

Comment: Please don't add such information as comments, edit your question instead. Also, how do you check the size of the local file? What happens to the data on the server side, does it get stored as a file as well? How large is that file then?

Comment: Thanks for your helping me. This is the first time I post question. I'll try to avoid mistakes as possible

Comment: I tried with some different sizes and it seems that it is always reporting 12 extra bytes. Can't figure out from where this 12 is coming.

Comment: I think curl add some header to upload file. But I can not find any document talk about that

Comment: No, curl doesn't modify the uploaded content at all.

Comment: @ThinhTran can you post this to curl mailing list or report a bug? Since nothing is said in documents, this looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Hi @taskinoor, when I tried a larger file(20170 bytes), curl_easy_getinfo return 20190 bytes. it is 20 extra bytes. I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

After change this line:

```
chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Transfer-Encoding: chunked");
```

to

```
chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Transfer-Encoding: ");
```

I get correct size in log.
The chunked encoding modifies the body of a message in order to transfer it as a series of chunks, each with its own size indicator, followed by an optional trailer containing entity-header fields [Ref](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.3.6.1).

But I have to use chunked. Is there any way to get correct uploaded data